# заменить числа 0 и 1

Tags: javascript

Задача, функция принимает числовую строку, если первое число в строке меньше пяти, заменить его на 0, если больше на 1.

Результат работы должен быть такой:

```
fakeBin('45385593107843568') --> '01011110001100111'
```

Вот мой код, не разберусь почему он возвращает кроме 0 и 1, ещё и оригинальные значения. Как это исправить ?

```js
function fakeBin(text){
 var result = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] < 5) {
   result += 0 + " ";
  } else {
   result += 1 + " ";
  }
  result += text[i] + " ";
 }
 return result.slice(0, result.length-1);
}

fakeBin('16');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function fakeBin(text){
 var result = '';
 for (var i of text) {
  if (i < 5)
   result += 0;
  else
   result += 1;
 }
 return result;
}

console.log(fakeBin('01234567890123456789'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`result += text[i] + " ";`  убери эту строчку

Answer (score 1):

Путь джедаев:

```js
const fakeBin = _ => _.split('').map(_ => +(!(_ < 5))).join('');

console.info(fakeBin('45385593107843568'));
```

Answer (score 0):

В таких простых задачах наиболее элегантно смотрится старая добрая рекурсия -

```js
const fakeBin = string => 
string.length ? ( parseFloat(string[0]) < 5 ? "0" : "1" ) + fakeBin( string.substring(1) ) : string;

console.log(fakeBin("45385593107843568"));
```

Comment: согласен. простая задача. но что происходит в коде у вас не совсем понятно. очень тяжело читать.

Comment: добавьте комментарий к своему коду ?

Answer (score 0):

Оригинальные значения возвращаются, потому что ты сам их дописываешь результат

```
result += text[i] + " ";
```

```js
function fakeBin(text) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] < 5) {
      result += 0 + " ";
    } else {
      result += 1 + " ";
    }
    // result += text[i] + " ";
  }
  return result.slice(0, result.length - 1);
}

console.log(fakeBin('16'));
```

Альтернативным способом решения может быть использование [функции replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
function fakeBin(text) {
  return text.replace(/\d/g, $0 => $0 < 5 ? 0 : 1);
}

console.log(fakeBin('45385593107843568'));
```

Кроме этого, для убирания лишнего пробела в конце, можно использовать [метод `trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Answer (score 0):

ещё несколько вариантов решения:

```js
function fakeBin(x) {
  return x.split('').map(n => n < 5 ? 0 : 1).join('');
}

console.info(fakeBin('45385593107843568'));
```

**или**

```js
function fakeBin(x) {
  return x.replace(/[1234]/g, '0').replace(/[56789]/g, '1')
}

console.info(fakeBin('45385593107843568'));
```

**или**

```js
const fakeBin = x => [...x].reduce((a, b) => a + (~~(+b / 5)), "")

console.info(fakeBin('45385593107843568'));
```

Comment: ничего не понятно! дайте исчерпывающие комментария.

Comment: Ну вот есть же новички, которые только начали изучать js и им не понятно что делают все эти методы и как по шагам происходит обработка всех символов. Я бы мог подумать что если они не понимают то это их проблема и что вероятнее всего они ещё не доросли, а ответ дан тем кто его сможет оценить по достоинству. Но вдруг вспомнил что у Вас иное мышление и что именно Вам не будет трудно описать пошагово каждый шаг! А иначе Вы и есть тот самый троль. К последнему я в момент написания первого сообщения ещё не пришел, но опять же Вы мне и с этим помогли.

Comment: разобрались. переубеждать вас я не стану. только попрошу объяснить этот кусок кода - `fakeBin( string.substring(1) )` он мне не понятен, что он делает. Какой его смысл. Мне и правда хочется разобраться. А вы вместо того чтобы помочь, начинаете хулиганить, и дразнить меня в комментариях.

Comment: в этой строчке вызывается функция в качестве аргументов которой передается текущая строка без первой буквы.

Comment: @OlmerDale простите меня если что не так.., очень тяжело мне даётся рекурсия. Никак не могу проследить её , в вашем примере. Магия одним словом. Благодарю вас за понимание!!